# Make changes to buttons and labels in an XML Ribbon during run-time

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, ms-office

I know there are several topics already on stackoverflow, but nothing that actually solves the problem. Here it is:
Because of some inherent problems with Ribbon Designer I decided to build my next Excel AddIn using XML Ribbon.
However, occasionally I need to make changes to the controls in the ribbon based on user selections. For example I need to change the text of a label, and also make some of the controls disabled in some cases. And here's where I hit a brick wall. It looks like there's no way to do it. I tried to put the logic in the onAction callback as follows:

```
public void LabelAction(IRibbonControl control)
{
    LabelControl label = (LabelControl)control;
    label.Label = "changed text";
}
```

But this cast doesn't work because apparently IRibbonControl interface has nothing to do with the RibbonControl class that LabelConrol inherits from.
I was also not able to find any other way to access any of the XML ribbon controls. Is there even a solution to this? Or should I stick to Ribbon Designer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this in a routine that sets the item label.

The xml would look like this:

```
      <button id="SkLabelTest1" getLabel="GetLabelTest" onAction="SkLabelTest1"/>
      <button id="SkLabelTest2" getLabel="GetLabelTest" onAction="SkLabelTest2"/>
```

The routine you are interested in is getLabel

I've done a noddy routine to demonstrate this.

First I added a property to ThisAddin.cs for it to read:

```
    public string _labelTest = string.Empty;
    public string LabelTest { get { return _labelTest; } set { _labelTest = value; } }
```

Then in my ribbon handling code I added the `getLabel` routine:

```
    public string GetLabelTest(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        switch (control.Id.ToLower())
        {
            case "sklabeltest2":
                if (Globals.ThisAddIn.LabelTest != string.Empty)
                    return Globals.ThisAddIn.LabelTest;
                else
                return "Label Test 2";
            default:
                return "Label Test 1";
        }
    }
```

This works by the `SkLabelTest1` button changing the text of `SkLabelTest2` and then invalidating the control to force the ribbon to reload it:

```
    public void SkLabelTest1(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn._labelTest = "Changed text";
        Globals.ThisAddIn._ribbon.InvalidateControl("SkLabelTest2");
    }
```

I've tested just in case and it changes the text OK. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make a comment because of my reputation. As a comment to [Charlie's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32692876/5077624), it is a perfect solution but on my side, I had to change one part.

I changed `public void SklabelTest1` function to this one below:

```
public void SkLabelTest1(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn._labelTest = "Changed text";
    this.ribbon.InvalidateControl("SkLabelTest2");
}
```

And also added this in the beginning of my ribbon class.

```
private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;
```

I hope it helps.